# Process remaining events when watchdog stops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-watchdog

I'm using the [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) python package to monitor changes in the filesystem.
I use it to check when files are created, modified or deleted and synchronize them in a cloud storage.

```py
import time

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler


class MyHandler(LoggingEventHandler):
    # Counter to see how many events are processed
    events = 0

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        self.events += 1
        # simulate some processing time
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(event.src_path, event.event_type, self.events, flush=True)


class myObserver(Observer):

    def on_thread_stop(self):
        print("Stopping thread")
        print("Remaining events: ", self.event_queue.qsize())
        # This will hang the observer thread
        self.event_queue.join()
        return self.on_thread_stop()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    observer = myObserver()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), "test_dir", recursive=True)
    # Tried to make the thread non-daemon, but it still stops processing events
    # observer.daemon = False

    observer.start()

    try:
        print("Writing 100 times to file")
        for i in range(100):
            with open("fstesting/test.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write("test\n")
    finally:
        # At this point, only at most a couple of events are processed.
        print("Stopping observer")
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()

        print("Done")
```

I've noticed that when observer is stopped, it stops all activity, producing and consuming events, which is the desired behaviour. I'm looking for a way that when the observer is stopped, it stops generating new events but keeps processing already queued events. Already tried to mess a bit directly with the queue calling `join()` but the observer thread holds and does not dispatch the events. I know the way would be extending `on_thread_stop` in `MyObserver` class but not sure how to make keep processing the events